Can you translate this phrase - "The Amplified Catholic"?
The intended meaning is for my new company name. I myself could be referred to as "The Amplified Catholic" for producing this B/W Catholic art in hyper-colorful, vibrant fashion (I would then use the translation for my company name).
Why Latin? So much of this old art contains Latin text, and Latin biblical phrases, that I'd like to use a Latin name. This artwork, is actually late 1800's - early 1900's, Catholic missal, B/W line-art, that I have colorized and revamped, in a kaleidoscopic fashion, for the modern age. I am basically "amplifying" old artwork...updating it in color, which is why I like the name "The Amplified Catholic".
Here are several versions I've found using multiple online translators:
Ampliata Catholica
Amplifica Catholica
Ampliatus Catholica
Catholicus Amplificatus
It should be noted, I am not here to learn to speak Latin at all, I am just looking for proper Latin translations for my art that currently has English names. All help would be appreciated.

Sorry, there is no gender-neutral way of saying "Catholic" in Latin.

Is there an implied noun, like "the amplified Catholic church/person/art/faith/saint/woman"? In English you don't have to specify it, but it often makes a difference in Latin.

"The Amplified Catholic" would be regarding the new artwork that I am producing and selling. I would like to use this as the name of my new business  - selling old (late 1800's - early 1900's), Catholic missal, B/W line-art, that has been colorized and revamped, in a kaleidoscopic fashion for the modern age. I am basically "amplifying" old artwork.

Any contextual information should go into the question. You can [edit] your question to add all that in and address clarifying comments.

Understood. Sorry, I am new around here.

Being new around here, can someone explain what I've done wrong in my OP so as not to get responses? I'm trying to be as clear and concise as possible. What am I not getting right? Why is this so difficult?

Your last option, catholicus amplificatus, is best. It is masculine, but that's okay; masculine is the inclusive gender in Latin for humans. If you want to include things as well as humans, catholicum amplificatum would be the way to go.

Hey Figulus,Thank you for that insight.

I kinda like Catholicum Amplificatum. I have another question though, would "Catholica Amplifico" work as well? I'm just asking...it's a little trimmed down and easier to say, for the non-Latin speaking clients I hope to have. I'm just trying to keep it short and easy to say. Let me know. Thanks again.
